# error when trying to use AutoCompletePopup

Tags: java, javafx

when I call AutoCompletePopup, I see this error:
`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.example.ontology.add_ps$1 (in module com.example.ontology) cannot access class impl.org.controlsfx.skin.AutoCompletePopup (in module org.controlsfx.controls) because module org.controlsfx.controls does not export impl.org.controlsfx.skin to module com.example.ontology`
how can I fix this?
(I connected controlsfx via maven. Maybe I need to add a new VM option?)

Comment: Are you [_Deploying an Application as a Module_](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+Deploying+an+Application+as+a+Module)?

Comment: Sounds like a module-info.java issue. That's assuming your project uses `module-Info.java`.

Comment: I also thought that my problem arose because of `module-Info.java` , but I have no idea how I can fix it @Sedrick

Comment: I think not. To be honest, I don't really understand what you're talking about, because I'm still not well versed in java @trashgod

Comment: Look at the image [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7428930/52966126-7e517000-3374-11e9-9c1a-ed66deabeb45.png). It looks like you need the line `javafx.base/com.sum.javafx.event to org.controlsfx.controls;` in module-info.java. I am not sure how to represent it there. Unforutnlaly, with JavaFX you can no longer simply concentrate on your code. You have to jump through hoops for things like this and to create executable Jars.